# User input 100 with readLine() isnt considered an Int? Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I made a simple code, which make two ranges, 1 from a..b and 1 from c..d. Then it checks if e is inside of at least one.

```
fun main(){
    val a = readLine()!!
    val b = readLine()!!
    val c = readLine()!!
    val d = readLine()!!
    val e = readLine()!!
    val f = (e in a..b || e in c..d)
    println(f)
}
```

The code works ok until one range has a number 100, then it starts giving me false. I saw that if i inserted toInt() in all readlines, it started working again.

Can someone explain me why? In readLine()!!, kotlin does not recognize numbers above 100 as Int?

Thanks!

Comment: readLine() always returns a String?, never an int.

Comment: But in this case it should not have worked when i try with 1..99

Comment: Not sure what all of your inputs were, but sumetimes it would actually work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `readLine` function in `Kotlin` returns an optional `String` as value, so if you don't explicitly convert it to an `Integer` with `toInt()` the range check will fail because it compares string numeric values.

For example the expression

```
"101" in "90".."102"
```

will return **false**.

Instead of the code

```
"101".toInt() in "90".toInt().."102".toInt()
```

will return **true**.

So, if you are comparing `Integer` values you should always convert the read values with `readLine()!!.toInt()`

Also, if you want to avoid unexpected crash, you should check for null values and potential parse errors:

```
val a = try { (readLine() ?: "").toInt() } catch (e: NumberFormatException) { 0 }
```

Comment: One tweak: `toInt()` _converts_ to an integer.  [Casting](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator) is something different (i.e. promising the compiler that the value is _already_ the required type — which in this case it's not).

Comment: @gidds Thank you for the tips. Just edited the answer with the correct term.

Comment: Thanks. (Though I hope you don't mind if I leave my comment up, as it seems to be a common point of confusion.)